# Partial Ordering over a subset of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Given a partial ordering $R$ over a set $S$ is it true that for every $A\subseteq S$ that $R$ is also a partial ordering over $A$?  I think so but I'm not sure.

Comment: More precisely, $R\cap(A\times A)$ is a partial order on $A$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is. The three defining properties of a partial order, reflexivity, antisymmetry and transitivity, contain only universal quantifiers and no existential quantifiers, and therefore can't be broken my removing elements from the set.

Comment: While it seems pretty obvious, is it something I would need to prove or is it so obvious that I could rely on it without proving it?

Comment: In an elementary first course, prove it.  In a research paper, assume your reader knows it.